# Usage of printf() in Cuda 4.0 Compilation Error

Tags: cuda, printf

I have a GTX 570 (Fermi architecture) which is of compute Capability 2.0. I have Cuda version 4.0 on my computer 
and I am using Ubuntu 10.10

With Cuda 4.0 it is possible to use `printf()` inside kernels. Here is an example code from page 125 of the Cuda 4.0 [programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf)

```
#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#define printf(f, ...) ((void)(f, __VA_ARGS__),0)
#endif


__global__ void helloCUDA(float f)
{
printf(“Hello thread %d, f=%f\n”, threadIdx.x, f);
}



void main()
{
helloCUDA<<<1, 5>>>(1.2345f);
cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error.

```
gaurish108 MyPractice: nvcc printf_inkernel.cu -o printf_inkernel
printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: expected an expression

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(10): error: unrecognized token

printf_inkernel.cu(15): warning: return type of function "main" must be "int"

8 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-4_printf_inkernel.cpp1.ii".
```

Why is it not recognizing printf? I tried adding the flag `-arch=sm_20` , but I get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've got a weird quote character at either end of `printf`'s formatter string.

If you copy and paste this program, it ought to compile and run without error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void helloCUDA(float f)
{
  printf("Hello thread %d, f=%f\n", threadIdx.x, f);
}

int main()
{
  helloCUDA<<<1, 5>>>(1.2345f);
  cudaDeviceReset();
  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 test.cu -run
Hello thread 0, f=1.234500
Hello thread 1, f=1.234500
Hello thread 2, f=1.234500
Hello thread 3, f=1.234500
Hello thread 4, f=1.234500
```

I don't understand the need for the weird macro which begins the program.  I'd get rid of it.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! The code is now working. Btw are you the same Jared Hoberock from the online Stanford video lectures on GPU computing? Those lectures are amazing! Thanks a ton for the wonderful material!