# Cuda 5.0 printf not working

Tags: cuda, printf

I am trying to run the cuda's printf example that I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003166/usage-of-printf-in-cuda-4-0-compilation-error) thread:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void helloCUDA(float f)
{
  printf("Hello thread %d, f=%f\n", threadIdx.x, f);
}

int main()
{
  helloCUDA<<<1, 5>>>(1.2345f);
  cudaDeviceReset();
  return 0;
}
```

It's being compiled with:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 test.cu -run
```

I got no output as well:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 test.cu -run
$
```

Here is my cuda version:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep_21_17:28:58_PDT_2012
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221
```

I am using bumblebee version 3:

```
$ optirun --version
optirun (Bumblebee) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2011 The Bumblebee Project

$ uname -a
Linux zeus 3.5.0-25-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 25 18:26:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change that `cudaDeviceReset()` call to a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call.  Also do [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) on the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call.  There may be a problem with your GPU or setup.